# Aptana 3 Studio Crashing on Start Up OSX Lion

Tags: macos, crash, aptana, aptana3

Aptana 3 Studio keeps crashing every time I launch it on my OSX Lion 10.7.4. I tried to use AppCleaner to remove Aptana 3 then re download and re install it. Still crashes every time I try to launch.

CRASH REPORT HERE:
http://pastebin.com/3HzPvZEZ

What can I do!? I need to get Aptana working for school!